# Truffle deployment address keeps changing

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing

I have a contract with a mapping that maps a number to an address and I'm trying to test the contract. Here is the relevant solidity code:

```
function _spawnPlayer(uint256 id) external {
    require(playerIndexToOwner[id] == address(0));
    players.push(Player(id));
    playerIndexToOwner[id] = address(this);
}
```

And here is how I'm testing that the created object is indeed assigned to the contract's address as an owner (the line line in the function).

```
it("Contract is assigned as the player's owner", () => {
    return BaseInstance._spawnPlayer(301).then(function (res) {
        BaseInstance.playerIndexToOwner.call(301).then((playerOwner) => {
            assert.equal(playerOwner, account, "Contract is not the spawned player's owner.")
        })
    })
});
```

My problem is for some reason `playerOwner` keeps changing every time I run the test and `account` is just accounts[0] so that should never change. So why does `playerOwner` keep changing? Is the address that deploys the contract not the same every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing `address(this)`, which is the address of the contract, not the address of the account that created it.

Perhaps you meant to use `msg.sender`, which would instead store the address of whatever called the function.

**EDIT**

If you're interested in the address that did the initial deployment, you may want something like this in the constructor. (`msg.sender` in the constructor is the account that created the contract.)

```
 owner = msg.sender;
```

See also https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/26/checking-the-sender-in-a-smart-contract/.

Comment: I actually meant to compare `playerOwner` and `BaseInstace.address` but yeah I was comparing the wrong variables.